# Invalid Token and if statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, time, printing

This is my first time programming in Python and I am not too sure what I am doing wrong. 
I am simply trying to print what the hour (time) is in words however I get the error "SyntaxError: invalid token" when I set the if statement to check

```
if current_hour == 05:
```

and when I change the 05 to 5 the If Statement simply does nothing.

This is my code:

```
import time

current_hour = time.strftime("%I")
print(current_hour)

if current_hour == 05:
    print("Five")
```

Thank you!

Comment: `05` is indeed syntax error in `python3`, because `0` is used for defining octal like `0o5` or hex like `0x15` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_hour` is a string. For this to work you need the following:

```
import time

current_hour = time.strftime("%I")
print(current_hour)

if current_hour == '05':
    print("Five")
```

or this:

```
import time

current_hour = int(time.strftime("%I"))
print(current_hour)

if current_hour == 5:
    print("Five")
```

Comment: "%I" return '05'

Comment: @WaketZheng ok then `current_hour == '05'`

Answer (score 0):

`time.strftime` returns a string like described in doc:

> Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string as specified by the format argument.

To compare in an if-statement you need to have the same datatype, so either convert the result to int or compare with a string like `"05"`

If you are not sure, which datatype is returned, you can check by using the `type()` method:

```
>>> print(type(current_hour))
<class 'str'>
```